# React replace componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, updates, deprecated, prop

Having the following method in my child component which updates state on prop changes which works fine

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    // update original states
    this.setState({
      fields: nextProps.fields,
      containerClass: nextProps.containerClass
    });
  }
```

I'm getting `Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code.`

and I try to update but till now without any success

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.fields !== prevState.fields) {
      return { fields: nextProps.fields };
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps);
    this.setState({
      fields: nextProps.fields,
      containerClass: nextProps.containerClass
    });
  }
```

because I get in infinite loop.

How do I update properly my state based in new props

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get loop because you set new state every time component updates. So if state updates, that means component updates, and you update it again.
Because of that, you need to prevent updating component on state change.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, nextProps) {
  if(prevProps !== this.props){
   console.log(nextProps);
   this.setState({
     fields: nextProps.fields,
     containerClass: nextProps.containerClass
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: By [React doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate), the second parameter is prevState. So, `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)`. I think you might review your logic

Answer (score 2):

You set the state, which will trigger another call and update which will call again and so on.
You must check if the value is changing first, and then set the state.

```
componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
    console.log(nextProps);
    if (nextProps.fields !== this.state.nextProps.fields){
        this.setState({
           fields: nextProps.fields,
           containerClass: nextProps.containerClass
        });
    }
  }
```

I recommended you to use hooks [see here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

I get there many times before.. All you need to do is to wrapp `this.setState({..` in some coditional.

You have `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)` so just compare if `nextProps.fields` and/or `nextProps.containerClass` are different than `this.props.fields` and `this.props.containerClass` - and only then set State

Btw, in CDM `nextProps` is actually `prevProps`