# react login register form sends empty data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, jwt, redux-form

I have a backend setup with node and express and frontend is React + Redux

The backend works well. I tested it all with insomina and i can successfully register a user and login.

On the front end side, everything looks ok except for the fact that when i try to login or register a user, it tells me that the input fields are required, which means that it sends an empty object to my backend. I also have a message in the console saying that componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) is depricated and suggests using getDerivedStateFromProps instead. The issue is that i am new to React and have no idea how to convert that block. Can someone tell me? Is that even why the form sends an empty object?

**EDIT: Added github repo for complete code**

https://github.com/onidemon/wh-evcharge

[image]

Register.js is below, both login and Register have a componentWillReceiveProps block which i think might be causing the issue. Not sure how to convert them to getDerivedStateFromProps if that is even the cause of the problem.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { registerUser } from "../../actions/authActions";
import classnames from "classnames";

class Register extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      password2: "",
      errors: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // If logged in and user navigates to Register page, should redirect them to dashboard
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors
      });
    }
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newUser = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
      password2: this.state.password2
    };

    this.props.registerUser(newUser, this.props.history);
  };

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col s8 offset-s2">
            <Link to="/" className="btn-flat waves-effect">
              <i className="material-icons left">keyboard_backspace</i> Back to
              home
            </Link>
            <div className="col s12" style={{ paddingLeft: "11.250px" }}>
              <h4>
                <b>Register</b> below
              </h4>
              <p className="grey-text text-darken-1">
                Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Log in</Link>
              </p>
            </div>
            <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <div className="input-field col s12">
                <input
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.name}
                  error={errors.name}
                  id="name"
                  type="text"
                  className={classnames("", {
                    invalid: errors.name
                  })}
                />
                <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                <span className="red-text">{errors.name}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="input-field col s12">
                <input
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.email}
                  error={errors.email}
                  id="email"
                  type="email"
                  className={classnames("", {
                    invalid: errors.email
                  })}
                />
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <span className="red-text">{errors.email}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="input-field col s12">
                <input
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.password}
                  error={errors.password}
                  id="password"
                  type="password"
                  className={classnames("", {
                    invalid: errors.password
                  })}
                />
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <span className="red-text">{errors.password}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="input-field col s12">
                <input
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.password2}
                  error={errors.password2}
                  id="password2"
                  type="password"
                  className={classnames("", {
                    invalid: errors.password2
                  })}
                />
                <label htmlFor="password2">Confirm Password</label>
                <span className="red-text">{errors.password2}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="col s12" style={{ paddingLeft: "11.250px" }}>
                <button
                  style={{
                    width: "150px",
                    borderRadius: "3px",
                    letterSpacing: "1.5px",
                    marginTop: "1rem"
                  }}
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light hoverable blue accent-3"
                >
                  Sign up
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Register.propTypes = {
  registerUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { registerUser }
)(withRouter(Register));
```

Login.js is below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { loginUser } from "../../actions/authActions";
import classnames from "classnames";

class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      errors: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // If logged in and user navigates to Login page, should redirect them to dashboard
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
    }

    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors
      });
    }
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const userData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };

    this.props.loginUser(userData);
  };

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div style={{ marginTop: "4rem" }} className="row">
          <div className="col s8 offset-s2">
            <Link to="/" className="btn-flat waves-effect">
              <i className="material-icons left">keyboard_backspace</i> Back to
              home
            </Link>
            <div className="col s12" style={{ paddingLeft: "11.250px" }}>
              <h4>
                <b>Login</b> below
              </h4>
              <p className="grey-text text-darken-1">
                Don't have an account? <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
              </p>
            </div>
            <form noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
              <div className="input-field col s12">
                <input
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.email}
                  error={errors.email}
                  id="email"
                  type="email"
                  className={classnames("", {
                    invalid: errors.email || errors.emailnotfound
                  })}
                />
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <span className="red-text">
                  {errors.email}
                  {errors.emailnotfound}
                </span>
              </div>
              <div className="input-field col s12">
                <input
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.password}
                  error={errors.password}
                  id="password"
                  type="password"
                  className={classnames("", {
                    invalid: errors.password || errors.passwordincorrect
                  })}
                />
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <span className="red-text">
                  {errors.password}
                  {errors.passwordincorrect}
                </span>
              </div>
              <div className="col s12" style={{ paddingLeft: "11.250px" }}>
                <button
                  style={{
                    width: "150px",
                    borderRadius: "3px",
                    letterSpacing: "1.5px",
                    marginTop: "1rem"
                  }}
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn btn-large waves-effect waves-light hoverable blue accent-3"
                >
                  Login
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Login.propTypes = {
  loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { loginUser }
)(Login);
```

EDIT: Added AuthActions.js

```
import axios from "axios";
import setAuthToken from "../utils/setAuthToken";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

import { GET_ERRORS, SET_CURRENT_USER, USER_LOADING } from "./types";

// Register User
export const registerUser = (userData, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/register", userData)
    .then(res => history.push("/login"))
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};

// Login - get user token
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/users/login", userData)
    .then(res => {
      // Save to localStorage

      // Set token to localStorage
      const { token } = res.data;
      localStorage.setItem("jwtToken", token);
      // Set token to Auth header
      setAuthToken(token);
      // Decode token to get user data
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      // Set current user
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};

// Set logged in user
export const setCurrentUser = decoded => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: decoded
  };
};

// User loading
export const setUserLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: USER_LOADING
  };
};

// Log user out
export const logoutUser = () => dispatch => {
  // Remove token from local storage
  localStorage.removeItem("jwtToken");
  // Remove auth header for future requests
  setAuthToken(false);
  // Set current user to empty object {} which will set isAuthenticated to false
  dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
};
```

Comment: Are you converting the object somewhere to a string before sending it with Axios? if yes might be the problem.

Also `componentWillReceiveProps` can not be the problem. If you need to move away from that because it is deprecated, I would recommend using `componentDidUpdate` in your case.

Comment: Any idea how to change that componentWillReceiveProps into a componentDidUpdate/getDerivedStateFromProps  ?

Comment: Try this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919347/react-replace-componentwillreceiveprops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked on your github project.
If I am not mistaken I haven't seen you using in your server  the `bodyparser.json()` function. You only use the `bodyParser.urlencoded()`, which convert url parameters into processable objects.
Add as well `bodyParser.json()`, then you would get the incoming data from the body of the request as well. Then you should have it I believe.

Comment: Wow! That was it, i completely missed that part. I spent so much time looking at the frontend that i completely forgot to give the backend another look, i assumed all was good. Thank you so much, you saved me!